# Flex App getting data from MySql via PHP - Examples

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I'm learning Flex, I already know how to submit data from a Flex App to a MySql DB using PHP.
But thats easy, but getting data... Thats a different story.

This isn't a question for sort of speak, its a request.

I wanted to ask to everyone that already learned how to do this, if it could send some Flex Projects (the ones you used to learn it in the first place) so that i could learn the same way by watching and trying.

From the complex to the more simple example.

If you have some that use Zend Amf or AMFPHP that would be great.

Send them to "eu@fabioantunes.net", or just post its url here.

Thanks :)

PS: Sorry for the English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KGTM,

You may have a look at:
http://corlan.org/2008/11/13/flex-and-php-remoting-with-zend-amf/

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should help: [Introduction to ZendAMF - Learn the basics of retrieving database content using this new PHP framework](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play?id=90).

Comment: Yes its hellpul and simple. And a good video tutorial to learn how Zend Amf works, and connect it to Flash Apps using only ActionScript.
But i really wanted some Flex Projects to see the Flex side mxml code i should use when doing Flash apps using Flex.